# z3 java api using mkOptimize

Tags: java, z3

I am using the optimization option of z3 in the java api via context.mkOptimize(). When I execute my code it will show me the following error:

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.microsoft.z3.Native.INTERNALmkOptimize(J)J

My Code:

```
Context context = new Context();
Optimize mkOptimize = context.mkOptimize();

IntExpr intTest = context.mkIntConst("test");
IntExpr intTen = context.mkInt(10);
BoolExpr assertInt = context.mkLe(intTest, intTen);

mkOptimize.Add(assertInt);
mkOptimize.MkMaximize(intTest);
mkOptimize.Check();
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in the java api? 
(The exception is thrown when creating the optimize object in the second line)

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. It was due to the system path which was pointing to two different versions of z3 libraries.